# Notepad ++ How to remove text from the url

Tags: notepad++, regex, notepad

I've been trying this for an hour and can't seem to get the right regular expression any ideas?

This:

> src="https://www.mywebsite.com/embedframe/84398934/need-this-text-and-the-forward-slash-before-it-removed" frameborder="0" width="600" height="400" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">

To This:

> src="https://www.mywebsite.com/embedframe/84398934" frameborder="0" width="600" height="400" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">

Comment: To be clear, you want to remove the last slash and the text after? Must this  be done for this specific URL or for any URLs in the file?

Comment: Yes. For all urls in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++ (notepad doesn't support regex):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `src="https://.*\K/[^/"]+(?=")`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
src="https://   # literally
.*              # 0 or more any character
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
/               # a slash
[^/"]+          # 1 or more any character that is not slash or double quote
(?=")           # positive lookahead, make sure we have a double quote after
```

**Result for given example:**

> `src="https://www.mywebsite.com/embedframe/84398934" frameborder="0" width="600" height="400" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">`

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: @NexusTees: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)